# Merging from libmysqld DB to MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, merge, libmysql

MySQL provides a zero configuration DB library (libmysqld) which can create a standalone DB.

Can this standalone DB be merged into MySQL at a lightning speed?

SQLite DB can be merged into another at a blink of an eye, regardless of how much data it bears. All you have to do:

```
open database mydata.db;
attach database 'moredata.db' as attchdb;
insert into maindb.table select * from attchdb.table;
```

Comment: you can link an existing db data file into mysql, but you can't merge it into another db. it'd become its own separate database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Marc. The application I'm working on is client-server based. The client(s) generate reports which are propagated to server & then are merged. On server side, we've shifted to MySQL & client side we still use SQLite. Merging this data into MySQL takes a lot of time in case of large data.